# Embed generated PDF-Files in IE8+

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pdf, internet-explorer-8, embedding

Iam trying to embed a client-side generated PDF (from jsPDF) as base64-encoded String in IE+8 with no success for hours.

I tried `object` and `embed`-tags as well as `iframe`.

Its not working at all :(

This is my example "PDF" which works in chrome and firefox:

```
<object type="application/pdf" style="width:100%;height:400px;" data="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgMSAwIFIKL1Jlc291cmNlcyAyIDAgUgovQ29udGVudHMgNCAwIFI+PgplbmRvYmoKNCAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggNzA+PgpzdHJlYW0KMC41NyB3CjAgRwpCVAovRjEgMTYgVGYKMTYgVEwKMCBnCjU2LjY5IDc4NS4yMCBUZAooSGVsbG8gd29ybGQuKSBUagpFVAplbmRzdHJlYW0KZW5kb2JqCjEgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvUGFnZXMKL0tpZHMgWzMgMCBSIF0KL0NvdW50IDEKL01lZGlhQm94IFswIDAgNTk1LjI4IDg0MS44OV0KPj4KZW5kb2JqCjUgMCBvYmoKPDwvQmFzZUZvbnQvSGVsdmV0aWNhL1R5cGUvRm9udAovRW5jb2RpbmcvU3RhbmRhcmRFbmNvZGluZwovU3VidHlwZS9UeXBlMT4+CmVuZG9iago2IDAgb2JqCjw8L0Jhc2VGb250L0hlbHZldGljYS1Cb2xkL1R5cGUvRm9udAovRW5jb2RpbmcvU3RhbmRhcmRFbmNvZGluZwovU3VidHlwZS9UeXBlMT4+CmVuZG9iago3IDAgb2JqCjw8L0Jhc2VGb250L0hlbHZldGljYS1PYmxpcXVlL1R5cGUvRm9udAovRW5jb2RpbmcvU3RhbmRhcmRFbmNvZGluZwovU3VidHlwZS9UeXBlMT4+CmVuZG9iago4IDAgb2JqCjw8L0Jhc2VGb250L0hlbHZldGljYS1Cb2xkT2JsaXF1ZS9UeXBlL0ZvbnQKL0VuY29kaW5nL1N0YW5kYXJkRW5jb2RpbmcKL1N1YnR5cGUvVHlwZTE+PgplbmRvYmoKOSAwIG9iago8PC9CYXNlRm9udC9Db3VyaWVyL1R5cGUvRm9udAovRW5jb2RpbmcvU3RhbmRhcmRFbmNvZGluZwovU3VidHlwZS9UeXBlMT4+CmVuZG9iagoxMCAwIG9iago8PC9CYXNlRm9udC9Db3VyaWVyLUJvbGQvVHlwZS9Gb250Ci9FbmNvZGluZy9TdGFuZGFyZEVuY29kaW5nCi9TdWJ0eXBlL1R5cGUxPj4KZW5kb2JqCjExIDAgb2JqCjw8L0Jhc2VGb250L0NvdXJpZXItT2JsaXF1ZS9UeXBlL0ZvbnQKL0VuY29kaW5nL1N0YW5kYXJkRW5jb2RpbmcKL1N1YnR5cGUvVHlwZTE+PgplbmRvYmoKMTIgMCBvYmoKPDwvQmFzZUZvbnQvQ291cmllci1Cb2xkT2JsaXF1ZS9UeXBlL0ZvbnQKL0VuY29kaW5nL1N0YW5kYXJkRW5jb2RpbmcKL1N1YnR5cGUvVHlwZTE+PgplbmRvYmoKMTMgMCBvYmoKPDwvQmFzZUZvbnQvVGltZXMtUm9tYW4vVHlwZS9Gb250Ci9FbmNvZGluZy9TdGFuZGFyZEVuY29kaW5nCi9TdWJ0eXBlL1R5cGUxPj4KZW5kb2JqCjE0IDAgb2JqCjw8L0Jhc2VGb250L1RpbWVzLUJvbGQvVHlwZS9Gb250Ci9FbmNvZGluZy9TdGFuZGFyZEVuY29kaW5nCi9TdWJ0eXBlL1R5cGUxPj4KZW5kb2JqCjE1IDAgb2JqCjw8L0Jhc2VGb250L1RpbWVzLUl0YWxpYy9UeXBlL0ZvbnQKL0VuY29kaW5nL1N0YW5kYXJkRW5jb2RpbmcKL1N1YnR5cGUvVHlwZTE+PgplbmRvYmoKMTYgMCBvYmoKPDwvQmFzZUZvbnQvVGltZXMtQm9sZEl0YWxpYy9UeXBlL0ZvbnQKL0VuY29kaW5nL1N0YW5kYXJkRW5jb2RpbmcKL1N1YnR5cGUvVHlwZTE+PgplbmRvYmoKMiAwIG9iago8PAovUHJvY1NldCBbL1BERiAvVGV4dCAvSW1hZ2VCIC9JbWFnZUMgL0ltYWdlSV0KL0ZvbnQgPDwKL0YxIDUgMCBSCi9GMiA2IDAgUgovRjMgNyAwIFIKL0Y0IDggMCBSCi9GNSA5IDAgUgovRjYgMTAgMCBSCi9GNyAxMSAwIFIKL0Y4IDEyIDAgUgovRjkgMTMgMCBSCi9GMTAgMTQgMCBSCi9GMTEgMTUgMCBSCi9GMTIgMTYgMCBSCj4+Ci9YT2JqZWN0IDw8Cj4+Cj4+CmVuZG9iagoxNyAwIG9iago8PAovUHJvZHVjZXIgKGpzUERGIDAuOS4wcmMyKQovQ3JlYXRpb25EYXRlIChEOjIwMTMwNzAzMTAwODM1KQo+PgplbmRvYmoKMTggMCBvYmoKPDwKL1R5cGUgL0NhdGFsb2cKL1BhZ2VzIDEgMCBSCi9PcGVuQWN0aW9uIFszIDAgUiAvRml0SCBudWxsXQovUGFnZUxheW91dCAvT25lQ29sdW1uCj4+CmVuZG9iagp4cmVmCjAgMTkKMDAwMDAwMDAwMCA2NTUzNSBmIAowMDAwMDAwMjA1IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDE0NDYgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDAwOSAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwMDg3IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDAyOTIgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDM4MyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwNDc5IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDA1NzggMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDY4MSAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwNzcwIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDA4NjUgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDk2MyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAxMDY1IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDExNTkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMTI1MiAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAxMzQ3IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDE2NzAgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMTc1MiAwMDAwMCBuIAp0cmFpbGVyCjw8Ci9TaXplIDE5Ci9Sb290IDE4IDAgUgovSW5mbyAxNyAwIFIKPj4Kc3RhcnR4cmVmCjE4NTYKJSVFT0Y=" >
  <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser. No biggie... you can <a href="/pdf/sample.pdf">click here to download the PDF file.</a></p>
</object>
```

Thanks in Advance for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 only supports base64 strings for images and the object tag(images only):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support